# How to set a value of a class

Tags: java, android, parameters, model

I have a simple Class with a inner class.

I want to set the following:

```
users[0][user_id]=8
users[1][user_id]=25
```

This is class:

```
public class ChatRequest {

    private List<Userbean> users;

    public List<Userbean> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<Userbean> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public static class Userbean {

        private int user_id;

        public int getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }

        public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
            this.user_id = user_id;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried it but without success.

How can I set the user id of the first user to 8 and the user id of the second user to 25?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. I have not much clue what you are asking.

Comment: These are basic of Java. This have nothing todo with the Android SDK or any other framework. Please learn the java basic first...

Answer (score 2):

These are java basic. Before refer to the Android SDK or something else please take a look into a java learning book/page.

However. Your "models" (or simple classes) are correct. To use these classes (and set the IDs you want) you need some instance of a `UserBean` first.

```
final ChatRequest.Userbean user0 = new ChatRequest.Userbean()
final ChatRequest.Userbean user1 = new ChatRequest.Userbean()
```

Then you can set the ID to it:

```
user0.setUser_id(8);
user1.setUser_id(25);
```

To finally add these users to the `ChatRequest` you need a instance of that as well:

```
final ChatRequest chatRequest = new ChatRequest();
```

Adding the users a simple call like that:

```
chatRequest.setUsers(Arrays.asList(user0, user1));
```

To be clear. These are the basic to create instances and set some values to classes/"models".

I think to answer your question we need some "preconditions". We assume that "someone" have already create some users and set it to the `ChatRequest` object which you receive in a "callback". To change some properties from the `Userbean` values can done in following way:

```
@Override
public void onChatRequestCreated(ChatRequest request) {
    request.getUsers().get(0).setUser_id(8);
    request.getUsers().get(1).setUser_id(25);
}
```

Comment: I set  `ChatRequest chatRequest = new ChatRequest();
        chatRequest.getUsers().get(0).setUser_id(8);` is error

Comment: Obviously. You don't have created a user yet and set it to the ChatRequest. Please read my answer carefully again... It answer all your queries.

Answer (score 1):

To set these values you should use this code:

users.get(0).setUser_id(8);

users.get(1).setUser_id(25);

Comment: and My Model is true?

Comment: Yes, your model and your classes are true. we talking about Java basics  not android :)